# Getting multiple lines of code in PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, extract

I want to get the multiple lines from a text file by using a pattern with the character at the beginning of the string to the character at the end of the string,and have an output that will be copied as multiple lines also.

```
<#
  get
  these
  lines
#>
```

I have tried using regex "<#(.+)#>", it gets the lines but it copies as one string only.

Output: <#  get  these  lines  #>

Comment: is it a multi-line string? or multiple strings?

Comment: its a multi-line string. actually, its a multi-line comments, but I don't think there's a built-in function in powershell that extracts multi-line comments, that is why I just used regex to extract that multi-line comments.

Comment: I runned 1. `$v = "<#\`n  get\`n  these\`n  lines`n#>"` 
2. `$r = [regex]::match($v, '<#.+#>', 's').value` 
3. `$r` 
I got `<#\`n  get\`n  these\`n  lines`n#>`. Can you show your code?

Comment: Is this text file in fact a PowerShell script file? In that case it might be safer to use [`[System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseFile(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.parser.parsefile?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) and extract the comments from the AST.

Answer (score 1):

**FileLines3.TXT:**

```
Random info1
<#
  get1
  these1
  lines1
#>
Random info2
<#
  get2
  these2
  lines2
#>
Random info3
```

**Code:**

```
$FileContent = Get-Content -Path "$PSScriptRoot\FileLines3.TXT" -Raw
$Lines = while($FileContent -match '(?ms)^\s*<#\s*$(?<Block>.*?)#>\s*$(?<After>.*)') {
    $Matches.Block.Split([Environment]::NewLine)
    $FileContent = $Matches.After
}
$Lines | Where-Object {$_}
```

**Results:**

```
  get1
  these1
  lines1
  get2
  these2
  lines2
```